# Sync Android contacts with server - syncing algorithm

Tags: android, algorithm, contacts, synchronization, android-syncadapter

I want to sync my android device's contacts with a server (1-way syncing: update server according to the device's contacts DB).

I've seen the SampleSyncAdapter example:
http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/SampleSyncAdapter/index.html

and a very good blog for understanding the pieces in the puzzle:
http://ericmiles.wordpress.com/2010/09/22/connecting-the-dots-with-android-syncadapter/

I understand that the sync logic itself is supposed to be in overriding onPerformSync() in a class extending AbstractThreadedSyncAdapter.

I was not, however, able to find an example for the syncing algorithm.
For instance, how do I sync just the diffs from the previous sync? am I supposed to keep a cache for the latest synced contacts and diff it with the current contacts DB?

Answer (score 0):

Ideally, you offload much of that work to the server.

If you're talking about a REST api type of server, you have two options.

1. First, go fetch an index of the rows in your dataset, and pass a parameter as part of the request to filter out rows changed since a date, and then fetch those specific rows only.

If that isn't supported by their REST API,

1. Fetch each row at its own URL, and use [HTML header fields](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html) to identify only what's changed.  See "If-Modified-Since" field for example.  This will tell the server that if the page you fetch is unchanged, not to bother returning it, but rather to send a 304 (not modified) response.  If it's 304, you know you don't need to change your DB.